# how to send php result data by angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

This is My html Page whare i add ng-app="myApp" And ng-controller="DashCtrl"

```
<form action="" ng-submit="dashForm(dashdata)" method="post"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="uid" ng-model="dashdata.uid"
       value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
        <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

And this is angular Code

```
myApp.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {        
            $scope.dashForm= function(dashdata) 
            {
               var encodedString = 'action=Userview'+'&id='+dashdata.uid;
               alert(encodedString);
                 $http({
                     method: 'POST',
                     url: 'ajaxprocess.php',
                     data: encodedString,
                     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                 })

                 .success(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                      if( data.trim() === 'admin') {
                         window.location.href ='dashbord.php';
                     } 
                     if( data.trim() === 'user') {
                         window.location.href ='test.php';
                     }  else {
                         $scope.errorMsg = data;
                         // statement
                     }
                 })            
            } 
        }]);
```

this send me an error ui is not defined,
alert messsege display but is show ui=undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="" ng-submit="dashForm()" method="post"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="uid" ng-model="dashdata.uid"
           ng-init="<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
        <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

and in controller:

```
var encodedString = 'action=Userview'+'&id='+$scope.dashdata.uid;
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
and a angular js error occur
  return logFn.apply(console, args);

Comment: @AtulPareek what did you get in dashdata?

Comment: i get all user data in dash bord from mysql.
like name,email, etc and i use edit delete button in each row
when i edit a row row id  combine with hindden text filed,
and id go to angular js but i read angular js not supoort hidden filed.